# Checking Distance Between Two Circles

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, physics

So I have this code that creates a number of balls and they get random x, y, and velocities, and they kind of just bounce around the screen, this part works great, but I want more. I have been trying to figure out how to get them to collide and bounce off in opposite directions. I've been trying to figure out what I've done wrong but I have not been able to figure it out for about 30 minutes, any suggestions?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('gamecanvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var ma = Math.random;
var mo = Math.round;

var ballcount = 5;
var balls = [];

function setup() {

    //canvas
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    for (i = 0; i < ballcount; i++) {

        //ball setup
        r = mo(ma() * 40) + 10;
        y = mo(ma() * (canvas.height - r));
        x = mo(ma() * (canvas.width - r));
        vx = mo(ma() * 20) - 10;
        vy = mo(ma() * 20) - 10;
        balls[i] = { x, y, vx, vy, r };

    }
}

function gameloop() {

    //clear
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.strokeStyle = 'white';

    //move
    for (i = 0; i < ballcount; i++) {

        balls[i].x += balls[i].vx;
        balls[i].y += balls[i].vy;

        //wall collision

        if (balls[i].x <= balls[i].r) {
            balls[i].x = balls[i].r;
            balls[i].vx *= -1;
        }
        if (balls[i].y <= balls[i].r) {
            balls[i].y = balls[i].r;
            balls[i].vy *= -1;
        }
        if (balls[i].x >= canvas.width - balls[i].r) {
            balls[i].x = canvas.width - balls[i].r;
            balls[i].vx *= -1;
        }
        if (balls[i].y >= canvas.height - balls[i].r) {
            balls[i].y = canvas.height - balls[i].r;
            balls[i].vy *= -1;
        }

        //ball collision
        for (j = 0; j < ballcount; j++) {
            if(i != j) {
                
                dx = balls[j].x - balls[i].x;
                dy = balls[j].y - balls[i].y;
                rs = balls[j].r + balls[i].r;
                
                if(Math.sqrt((dx * dx) - (dy * dy)) < rs) {
                    balls[i].vx *= -1;
                    balls[j].vx *= -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //draw
    c.beginPath();
    for (i = 0; i < ballcount; i++) {

        c.moveTo(balls[i].x + balls[i].r, balls[i].y);
        c.arc(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, balls[i].r, 0, 7);

    }
    c.stroke();
}

setup();
setInterval(gameloop, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
    <head>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <title>Bslls</title>
        
    </head>
    
    <body id="body">
        <canvas id="gamecanvas"></canvas>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: while i can't help, i just wanted to say this is pretty cool. Some of them look like they start bouncing mid screen off of something though.

Comment: (dx * dx) - (dy * dy) can be negative value. Math.sqrt doesn't work with negative values. Try with Math.sqrt(Math.abs((dx * dx) - (dy * dy)))

Comment: @J.García well It can't be that because then you would be multiplying a negative by a negative which is positive.

Comment: First of all, `(dx * dx) - (dy * dy)` should be `(dx * dx) + (dy * dy)`. Secondly, multiplying the velocities by -1 is not the physically correct way to resolve collisions; momentum should be conserved along the contact normal vector (which is simply `(dx, dy)` in this case). Most importantly, the balls can stick to each other as you do not take the finite timestep into account when detecting collisions; this is difficult to solve accurately, but a quick hack is to only treat the intersection of 2 balls as a collision if they are travelling towards each other, which works well at low speeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

There are two subproblems: finding the collision point and reflecting the trajectories.

To find the collision point, you can reason as follows:

- inflate one ball by the radius of the other and let the other reduce to a point;
- consider the relative speeds of the ball and the point (i.e. vector difference), and move the ball to the origin.

Now you have a fixed circle and a point moving along a straight line. You can find the first intersection point between the circle and the line by solving a quadratic equation. The most convenient is to use the parametric equation of the point motion vs. the implicit equation of the circle. For the same price, you get the meeting time.

To reflect the trajectories, consider that the normal to the circle at the intersection point is the bisector of the incident and reflected directions. In case of a perfect elastic shock, the speed after reflection is the same as before.

Now by undoing the initial transformations, you can find the meeting point and the new directions of the two balls.

Just a bit of vector calculus :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do something similar in the past, I came across some libraries that simulate physics with js, one of them is http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/.
it is a simple librarie.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether the distance between two balls is smaller than the sum of their radii.

```js
//let b1 be ball-1 and b2 be ball-2

var distance = Math.sqrt((b2.x - b1.x) ** 2 + (b2.y - b1.y) ** 2);
if(b1.r + b2.r <= distance) {

//colliding

}
```

but in your case as the balls are moving too fast in a small space, you are unable to detect the collision properly.

I.e., your collision-detecting math is working properly, the problem is that you are not able to detect collisions at the right time!

Your balls will move in a straight line, so consider two balls moving in a straight line, you have to check whether the balls will collide when they are at any part of their corresponding motion line.

There will be some more complex math involved!